# Change the Input Type of Inputs in Alert Controller in Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, alert, angularfire

Is the modifying of input type in Alert Controller is possible using the only button inside the prompt itself?

Problem:

1. I want to change the input type "password" into "text" when the user press the View Password button. Do you have any suggestion about that?

[image: The Alert Controller]

**change password code (profile.ts)**

```
 async changePassword(){
    let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Change Password',
      subHeader: 'Fill up the fields.',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'oldPassword',
          placeholder: 'Old Password.',
          type: 'password'
        },
        {
          name: 'newPassword',
          placeholder: 'New Password.',
          type: 'password',
          value: this.generatePassword(8) //This generate the password
        },
        {
          name: 'newPasswordConfirm',
          placeholder: 'Confirm New Password',
          type: 'password'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked.');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'View Password',
          handler: data => {
            data.newPassword.type = 'text'; //Error exists
            return false;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }//
```

**The actual error**

[image: Error]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The data.newPassword.type = 'text' throws an error.  "Cannot create property 'type' on string in alert controller"

Comment: But when you click on `View Password` your alert dismissed automatically. in this case you can try `PopoverController` with custom component

Comment: That is complete code for the form sir. I put the whole form inside the alert controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you asking is not possible with AlertController. It is a very basic component which only returns a json object to you, not the form itself.

For your purposes you should do as Ravi suggested in the comments, [use a PopoverController with custom component.](https://www.tutorialandexample.com/ionic-popover/)

You can get the remaining portions from the link above but here are the parts you care about:

**Popovercomponent.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from
'@angular/core';
 import {PopoverController} from '@ionic/angular';
 import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-popovercomponent',
   templateUrl: './popovercomponent.page.html',
   styleUrls: ['./popovercomponent.page.scss'],
 })
 export class PopovercomponentPage {

    form = this.formBuilder.group({
     newPassword: [''],
     oldPassword: [''],
     newPasswordText: [''],
     oldPasswordText: [''],
   });

   showPassword = false;
   doUpdate = false;

   constructor(private popover:PopoverController,
               private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  toggleShowPassword(): void {
    this.showPassword = !this.showPassword;

    if (showPassword) {
      this.form.patchValue({
        oldPasswordText: this.form.oldPassword.value,
        newPasswordText: this.form.newPassword.value
      });
    } else {
      this.form.patchValue({
        oldPassword: this.form.oldPasswordText.value,
        newPassword: this.form.newPasswordText.value
      });
    }

  }

  cancel(): void {
    this.popover.dismiss();
  }

   update(): void {
     this.doUpdate = true;
     this.popover.dismiss();
   }
 }
```

**Popovercomponent.page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <form>
      <ion-row *ngIf="!showPassword">
        <ion-col><input type="password" [formControlName]="oldPassword" placeholder="Old Password"></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngIf="showPassword">
        <ion-col><input type="text" [formControlName]="oldPasswordText" placeholder="Old Password"></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngIf="!showPassword">
        <ion-col><input type="password" [formControlName]="newPassword" placeholder="Confirm new password"></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngIf="showPassword">
        <ion-col><input type="text" [formControlName]="newPasswordText" placeholder="Confirm new password"></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button color="success" expand="block" (click)="update()">Update</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button color="success" expand="block" (click)="togglePassword()">View Password</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button color="success" expand="block" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </form>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Once added to your main code (which is not posted in your question) you will be able to access the data via the popover object.

Answer (score 1):

I would assign an id to each input

```
inputs: [
    {
      name: 'oldPassword',
      placeholder: 'Old Password.',
      type: 'password', 
      id: 'new-id'
    },
```

Then I would change the input type like so

```
let passwordInput = document.getElementsByClassName('new-id');
passwordInput.setAttribute('type', 'text')
```

Comment: This is a nice little workaround. I guess you meant to use `getElementById`?
`const passwordInput = document.getElementById('new-id');
passwordInput.setAttribute('type', 'text')`